# mean for rolling a die multiple times

Tags: probability

What is the mean of rolling a fair die $10000$ times in a row?

I calculated the mean value to be $3.5$: I did $(1+2+3+4+5+6)/6$, which is $3.5$, and then multiplied it by $10000$ because the die is being rolled $10000$ times and divided by the $10000$ to find the mean? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, since expectation is linear and the sum of expectations is the expectation of the sum.

Comment: $3.5$ is the expectation of the sample average, but you are unlikely (probability below $0.3\%$) to get an average of exactly $3.5$ from your sample, though you have a probability of over $99.6\%$ of getting an average between $3.45$ and $3.55$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that's a fair die you know that

$f(x=1) = f(x=2) = ... = f(x=6) = 1/6$

Then we can compute the expected value of the discrete variable $x$ as
$$
\mathbb{E}[x] = \sum_{i=1}^{6}x\cdot f(x) = \frac{1}{6}\left(1+2+3+4+5+6\right)= \frac{21}{6} = 3.5
$$

Since you already know the *probability mass function* $f(x)$ you're good to go, you don't need to estimate it by sampling 10000 times.

Answer (score 1):

The mean number of any roll is always the same, $\frac{1}{6}(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) = 3.5$

Since all rolls are independent events, each roll has an average roll value of $3.5$

After $10000$ rolls, the mean value of all of them would be like taking the mean of a list with $10000$ $3.5$'s. This is just $3.5$ and so you're doing it correct.